# Why aren't variables passing to function?

Tags: php, function, variables, session-variables

```
function User_CustomValidate(&$usr, &$pwd) {

     global $usr2; 
     $usr = $usr2;  
        $this->setCurrentUserName($usr); // Set the current user name 
        return TRUE;
}
```

I have a simple function that I need to populate.  But $usr will not allow for any variable to be passed to it.  This is going to hold a session user id.  If I set it to $usr = '445' it logs everyone into the site with user 445's credentials - so it works.

However at first I was trying to set $usr = $_SESSION['uid'] to get the user info.  uid data was passing fine in code but I was getting nothing for $usr.

So right after gather the session uid I added $usr2 = $_SESSION['uid'].  All of my pages can display $usr2.  But $usr will not update.  The only thing I can get $usr to accept is a static entry and that won't work for dynamic user login.

Edit:

Echo notes below -

```
if (IsLoggedIn()) echo "logged in"; // it returns "logged in"
echo "userlevel:" . CurrentUserLevel(). "---"; // it returns nothing relies on username
echo "username:" .  CurrentUserName();  // it returns nothing relies on function
echo "userid:" .  CurrentUserID (); // it returns nothing relies on username
echo "usr:" . $usr;  //returns nothing
echo "usr2:" .  $usr2;  //returns uid
echo "session" .  $_SESSION['uid']; //returns uid
```

Another note - If I have $usr = $usr2 outside of the function on the page then it passes uid info on for $usr... but not to the function that needs it.

Comment: Echo out $_SESSION['uid'] to check if it has been set ?

Comment: Please, don't use global inside a function. If you need an external value, add a parameter instead.

Comment: Yes if I echo out $_SESSION['uid'] it passes.

Comment: And just using global right now to figure out why $usr is not accepting variables.

Comment: Also if I create $usr = $usr2 outside of the function it passes the uid information to $usr just fine.  However the function does not work.